# URL rewriting from id to title

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting

I've got a page with the following url: `website.com/foo/bar`

Where foo is the page's php file and bar is the corresponding id to be used to pull in the data from the database.

I'm not using any sort of framework trickery. Just an htaccess to remove the .php and extensions and to process the page `foo.php` with the id as its not in a sub-folder.

Anyways, bar is just a number (like I said corresponds with database row id). For SEO and general readability in a users history I want to go to the more popular `website.com/foo/this-is-the-name` format (what is this format called??).

Currently my code is:

```
require('neou_cms/framework/framework.php');

$id = filter(basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

// no id
if (empty($id)) {
    header('Location: ../portfolio');
}

$projects = Nemesis::select("*", "projects", "published = '1' AND id = {$id}");
$row_projects = $projects->fetch_assoc();
$totalRows_projects = $projects->num_rows;

// no results, bad id
if ($totalRows_projects <= 0) {
    header('Location: ../portfolio');   
}
```

If figure I would do the following (1) make it so that the pages linking to foo instead go to the page title e.g. /this-is-the-name (2) in foo i'd make it so that `$id` removes the dashes from the name and searches the database for the row using a select statement and the title.

However I feel like this is slow... Is there a better way to do it that wouldn't require me changing the current flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine. The `this-is-the-name` part of your url (`website.com/foo/this-is-the-name`) is commonly called a "[slug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug)". If you'll be querying a database table on the slug, just make sure the slug column has an index and the query should perform reasonably well.

I would also like to point out that you have a SQL injection vulnerability in the code you've posted. Consider binding `$id` as a parameter in a parameterized query instead of dynamically including it in a where clause.

Comment: I only have one table for foo, there is no slug column, so it would be a semantic search on the title column using `this is the name`. Would that be bad?

Comment: If you search the title column for a non-exact match string, the query will likely not use an index and be slow as your table grows large. I recommend adding a separate slug column with an index to support fast queries on exact string matches.

Comment: implemented. had to write a script to generate slugs for all of the past db entries but works fast enough for my liking. thanks!